# Есть ли плагин на подобии emmet, но для .jsx файлов в vscode

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

Есть ли в vscode плагин который бы ускорял написание html разметки в jsx файлах, как это реализовано в emmet, то есть ставишь точку и автоматически предлагает вставить div, но чтобы это работа в return ( )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56311467/configure-emmet-for-jsx-in-vscode

Comment: https://dev.to/sreeharshrajan/code-reactjs-faster-by-enabling-emmet-for-javascript-and-typescript-in-vs-code-820